# I want to make a dropdown container in my script

Tags: godot

I want to create a dropdown container to organize my export variable. Is it possible to create a custom dropdown container in the script?

Like this:
[image: Image in inspector]

Comment: Which version of godot? It's possible (but a bit of a pain) to do it in 3.x. I *think* there may be an easier way to do it in 4, but I haven't used 4 yet.

Comment: @yoozer8 It is not yet implement in Godot 4, but there will be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is another approach to do this. It also requires the script to be [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html).

What we need for this approach as a common prefix for the variables you want to group. The advantage is that we don't need `_get` and `_set`:

```
tool
extends Node

var custom_position:Vector2
var custom_rotation_degrees:float
var custom_scale:Vector2

func _get_property_list():
    return [
        {
            name = "Custom",
            type = TYPE_NIL,
            hint_string = "custom_",
            usage = PROPERTY_USAGE_GROUP
        },
        {
            name = "custom_position",
            type = TYPE_VECTOR2
        },
        {
            name = "custom_rotation_degrees",
            type = TYPE_REAL
        },
        {
            name = "custom_scale",
            type = TYPE_VECTOR2
        }
    ]
```

As you can see we define a category with a `name` that will appear in the Inspector panel, and the `hint_string` is the prefix we will use. It is important to put the category before the properties in the array.

See: [Adding script categories](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html#adding-script-categories)

**Addendum**: Using `PROPERTY_USAGE_CATEGORY` will produce a named header, similar to the one that says "Node2D" on the picture on the question. Use `PROPERTY_USAGE_GROUP` to make a collapsible group.

Comment: I tried something like this before using the approach described in my answer and I could never get it to work...

Comment: This creates a header, not a collapsible category. Referring to the screenshot in the question, `Custom` would act as `Node2D` rather than as `Transform`. That was why I "couldn't get it to work". (Can't guarantee my answer doesn't behave the same way; I reorganized stuff so I wouldn't have to worry about this)

Comment: @yoozer8 Ah, I overlooked that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but (in my opinion) it is a bit ugly and clutters up your script. You need to mark your script as a `tool` script and override the `_get`, `_set`, and `_get_property_list` functions.

An example based on your screenshot (not 100% sure this works exactly as-is; I'm also basing it on a recent project where I have since removed it and somewhat reorganized the project/code/node because the slightly nicer UI wasn't worth the additional clutter in the script):

```
tool
extends Node2D

# Note that these are NOT exported
var actual_position: Vector2
var actual_rotation: float
var actual_scale: Vector2

# Function to enumerate the properties to list in the editor
#  - Not actually directly/automatically backed by variables
#  - Note the naming pattern - it is {group heading}/{variable}
func _get_property_list():
    var props = []
    props.append({name="transform/position", type=TYPE_VECTOR2})
    props.append({name="transform/rotation deg", type=TYPE_FLOAT}) # might not exist; look at docs to determine appropriate type hints for your properties
    props.append({name="transform/scale", type=TYPE_VECTOR2})
    return props


# Now the get/set functions to map the names shown in the editor to actual script variables
# Property names as input here will match what is displayed in the editor (what is enumerated in _get_property_list); just get/set the appropriate actual variable based on that
func _get(property: String):
    if property == "transform/position":
        return actual_position
    if property == "transform/rotation deg":
        return actual_rotation
    if property == "transform/scale":
        return actual_scale

func _set(property: String, value):
    if property == "transform/position":
        actual_position = value
        return true
    if property == "transform/rotation deg":
        actual_rotation = value
        return true
    if property == "transform/scale":
        actual_scale = value
        return true
    # Not a supported property
    return false
```

Note that this answer is based on Godot 3.4. I'm not sure if a simpler approach is (or will be) available in Godot 4.

Comment: Your [`_get_property_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-property-list) should return the `Array`, and [`_set`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set) should return `true` when it sets the variables, `false` otherwise. Also there is no `TYPE_FLOAT`, I think you want `TYPE_REAL`.